# Can we have Class.Empty Object like we have in String.Empty

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using .NET 3.5. I am creating a simple class and wants to make sure that the class after processing should not be null or should not be a new too..

So if we can just Test it like that

```
Dim objClass as new Class()

' do some processing with the class '
' and then.. check that if this object returned is not empty '

If (objClass = Class.Empty) Then
//Do stuff
Else
//Do Other Stuff
End If
```

is there a way we can create this empty Field like we have in String.Empty?

Comment: Basically we are kind of finding that 

if (objclass=nothing or objClass=new Class()) Then

End if

So, I just want to shorten it out to Just Empty Field or keyword to enter in that class.

Comment: I even used this

Public Shared ReadOnly Empty As New Class


But still it does not do the job here. This is the same type of code used in String.Empty

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx

Comment: I would assume that objClass is either an instance of Class or the constructor for class threw an exception. It would be good to also see the code between the call of the constructor and the if-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But in your example the class isn't technically empty.  You've created an instance of Class using the default constructor.  Who knows, the default constructor may have initialised over 10MB of string content.   What your code is technically checking is, is the class equal to it's default state just after being constructed.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa903373) for example of VB constructors and what is happening.

If you correctly implemented CompareTo(...) you could call

```
If (objClass.CompareTo(new Class()) == 0) Then 
 //Do stuff 
Else
 //Do Other Stuff 
End If
```

But that would seem overkill / expensive, but the only way it would work.

Another option would be:   (sorry c# based example)

```
Interface IEmpyClass
{
   bool IsEmptyClass{get;}
}

public class Class : IEmptyClass
{
   public bool IsEmptyClass{get; private set;}

   public Class()
   {
     IsEmptyClass = true;
   }

   public void DoSomething()
   {
       // Do something
       IsEmptyClass = false;
   }
}
```

You would be responsible for implementing the example and changing the property when the class state changed from "empty", but that would be quicker in code, etc. and could cope when clases have constructors with members.   It could be checked just with

```
If (objClass.IsEmptyClass) Then 
 //Do stuff 
Else
 //Do Other Stuff 
End If
```

Comment: Yes Paul.. You are right I am checking the class object if it is null or if it is in default state.. Basically in the processing I am sending this object to somewhere and getting it back as 

objClass=ProcessClass(objClass)

Now here I need to know whether this class object now contains Data in it or not..

Comment: See edit in answer above, sorry examples are in C#.  You could say that this is a version of the "NULL object" design pattern referred to by Arseny

Comment: Thanks Paul... See my answer below... And if possible tell me if there is any better thing I can do in it?

Answer (score 4):

there is design pattern [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called `null` for reference types, and `new T()` for value types.

Comment: but string.empty is not  null for reference types

Comment: Yes Arseny it is not null.. But I want this empty field to validate both Null and New Object at the same time... Can it be done? Is their any code that I should write?

Comment: Maybe you mean `default(T)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I do this for anyone following.

**Demo Class:**

```
public class MyClassName
{
    // Only the property Empty can call this constructor
    private MyClassName(){}

    //everyone can call this constructor
    public MyClassName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        //during construction GET only properties can be written to.
        IsEmpty = false;
    }

    public bool IsEmpty { get; } = true
    public static MyClassName Empty { get { return new MyClassName(); } }

    public string Name { get; } = string.Empty;
}
```

**Real Use of Class on**
[GitHub](https://github.com/gavin1970/Chizl.TextConverter/blob/master/Chizl.TextConverter/models/ColumnDefinition.cs)

**Demo function passing class**

```
public void MyFunction(MyClassName myClass)
{
    if(myClass == null || myClass.IsEmpty)
        return;
    
    string name = myClass.Name;
    // Do something.
}
```

**Example Call 1:**

```
MyFunction(MyClassName.Empty);
```

**Example Call 2:**

```
var myClass = new MyClassName("Some Text");
MyFunction(myClass);
```

Comment: You are not checking if myClass is null in your "Demo function". It could throw a NullPointerException

Comment: The example was to show how to emulate the class IsEmpty and the passing of Empty.  The demo method would be anyone else calling it so syntax wasn't really my point. Ill go ahead and update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an Extension method called "Empty" on "Class" which takes one parameter of type var (if .net 4.0) or object (older version). The implementation of this extension method will check whether its a null or not initialised to the default state and return true or false.

Comment: Why would this have to be an extension method?

Comment: So that every class will have "Empty" method with a generic implementaion of Empty logic using an interface. Have a look at following code.
public static class ObjectExtensions {
 public static bool Empty(this object obj) {
  IEmpty otherObj = obj as IEmpty;
  if (otherObj == null) 
   return true;
  else if (otherObj.IsEmpty)
   return true;
  else
   return false
 }
}

Now if any class that implement IEmpty interface gets true if its null or IsEmpty is set to true otherwise false. If any class that don't implement IEmpty will always get true as IsEmpty never been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

OK Guys Thanks for your help.. I have reached here so far.. Working very good now.

```
Public Class cc
    Private _obj As Boolean = False
    Public _index As Integer = 0

    Public ReadOnly Property IsEmpty() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _obj
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Index() As Integer
        Get
            Return _index
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _obj = False
            _index = value //I need to set it to false for every property of that class.
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New()
        _obj = True
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Empty(ByVal obj As cc) As Boolean
        If Not (obj Is Nothing) Then
            If Not (obj.IsEmpty()) Then
                Return False
            End If
        End If
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

In separate class:

```
Dim Sc As New cc()
//'Sc=Nothing
Sc.Index=1

If (cc.Empty(Sc)) Then
    Label1.Text = "Empty"
Else
    Label1.Text ="Not Empty"
End If
```

Comment: Please comment on it guys.. if there is something wrong here.. I guess this can be done without Interface too. But anyway thats not a thing to worry..

Comment: It definitely looks a workable solution if it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks You all... :)

Regards.
Mohit Bhardwaj.

Comment: Two things: 1) The shared Empty function looks more like IsNullOrEmpty and could be written as `Return obj IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not obj.IsEmpty` (no parentheses on IsEmpty, it's a property) 2) If you want to be able to say `obj = cc.Empty`, you will need to override the equality operator (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/05/12/equality-isn-t-easy.aspx and the articles it links to for information on how to do this correctly)

Answer (score 0):

To define an Empty field you have to create a static readonly property in your class.
The trouble if you have also to define the = operator on your class.

For example, if your class contains only one field of type string, you can 
define an = operator that check if the string fields of the two instances are equals.